# dpkg-shlibdeps fails with "no dependency information found"

Tags: package-management, dpkg, cuda

I am building a custom debian package for tensorflow. At some point, when I run

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

I get:

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcurand.so.9.1 (used by debian/libhal-tensorflow-cc/usr/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so)
Hint: check if the library actually comes from a package.
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/libhal-tensorflow-cc.substvars debian/libhal-tensorflow-cc/usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so debian/libhal-tensorflow-cc/usr/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so returned exit code 2
debian/rules:9: recipe for target 'binary' failed
```

I looked up this page: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/dpkg-dev/dpkg-shlibdeps.1.en.html
and tried to follow the steps performed by this tool to get the dependency information:

```
$ dpkg -S libcurand.so.9.1
cuda-curand-9-1: /usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so.9.1
cuda-curand-9-1: /usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so.9.1.85
```

Actually, there is a corresponding .shlibs file for this package:

```
$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/cuda-curand-9-1.shlibs
libcurand 9.1 cuda-curand-9-1
```

I checked if the package is actually installed, and it is:

```
$ apt list | grep cuda-curand-9-1

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

cuda-curand-9-1/unknown,now 9.1.85-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

so I am out of ideas what it complains about

Comment: Please refer to this, I resolve this problem by using pbuilder: https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues/19217

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I was linking against a wrong so. The library `libtensorflow_framework.so` was using:

```
/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcurand.so.9.1
```

while I had installed

```
/usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so.9.1
```

That's because the library `libtensorflow_framework.so` was built on a different machine, where CUDA was installed in a different location.